# Prove that D + A, where D is a diagonally positive matrix and A is a skew symmetric matrix, is always invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As the question says, D is a diagonally positive matrix(i.e all the diagonal elements are > 0 and remaining are 0) and A is a skew symmetric matrix. Is there a way to prove this. I understand that I have to prove that the eigen values of (D+A) are non-zero

Comment: I realized that. But I am trying to find the eigen values of (D+A). how can i get a non zero eigen value of the matrix(D+A) to show that it is non singular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is invertible, because it is positive definite:
Let $B=D+L-L^T$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with positive entries and $L$ is the lower part of the skew symmetric matrix $A$ , and $-L^T$ is the upper part. Then you have
$$(Bx,x)=((D+L-L^T)x,x)=(Dx,x)+(Lx,x)-(L^Tx,x)=(Dx,x)+(L^Tx,x)-(L^Tx,x)=(Dx,x)>0$$
for each nonzero vector $x$.
We used $(Lx,x)=(Lx)^Tx=x^TL^Tx=(x,L^Tx)=(L^Tx,x)$

**Addition:** Why from $(Bx,x)>0,\,\,\forall x\neq 0$ follows that $B$ is invertible ? Because, if you assume that it is not, then there is $x\neq 0: Bx=0$. Then, you get $(Bx,x)=(0,x)=0$ which is a contradiction.